# Arraylist.contains won't check string

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, java.util.scanner

I want to build a program that takes inputs a set number of strings (`int T`) via scanner and stores them inside an arraylist. Then I want to check the input to see if it matches or contains characters from another Array.

Example Input:

```
1
ABCD
```

Example Output:

```
Good
```

Problem: When I run the code I do not get a "Good" or "Bad" output, instead I get an error and the debug console launches.

Exact Error:

```
Scanner.throwFor() line: not available. Source not found
```

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class RNA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String X [] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};  // Array to be checked against


        List<String>A = new ArrayList();  // ArrayList to be imported

        Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How Many Sets of Strings do you want?");

        int T = q.nextInt(); // number of Strings to be imported
        q.nextInt();  // allows to reset Scanner

        for(int i = 0 ; i < T; i ++){

            A.add(q.nextLine());  //imports stuff to add to array A
        }


        Iterator<String> ListChecker = A.iterator(); 

        while((ListChecker.hasNext())) {   //continues as long as DNA Check has an index to go to 

            if (A.contains(X)) {                  //Checks A for X
                System.out.println("Good");       //Prints out good if the check is good
            }
            else {

                System.out.println("Bad");        //Prints out bad if the check is bad
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Does it give you a line on which the error is occurring?

Comment: Can you show us where it's occurring?

Comment: Could it be that you are checking for the string object? Because the string object is kinda finicky in that the values might be equal but the reference is not.

Comment: I think you should check elements of array. so, it should be if (A.contains(X[0])). of course this sholud be checked for every element of array

Comment: You check if A contains an Array of String (directly the `String[]` object), not if it contains a String inside this array (What is inside this `String[]`). Your code is a mess (use better names and so on to improve).

Comment: Never use the same scanner for both nextInt() and nextLine(). They bug out. Use two scanners, one for ints, and one for strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- You should use `q.next();` to consume the new line character instead of `q.nextInt();` which is basically you are getting input mismatch exception.
- You are doing `list.contains(Array)` which is not supported. If you wish to check for each input from user whether its there in Array X then you should probably do something like:

  ```
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(X);
  while((ListChecker.hasNext())) {   //continues as long as DNA Check has an index to go to 
     if (list.contains(ListChecker.next())) {                  //Checks A for X
         System.out.println("Good");       //Prints out good if the check is good
     } else {
         System.out.println("Bad");        //Prints out bad if the check is bad
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You check if A contains an Array of String (directly the `String[]` object), not if it contains a String inside this array (What is inside this `String[]`).

Replace it with

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(X);
```

So you have a List from your Array, and then use contains

```
result.contains(A)
```

Your code could look like this

```
List<String> xAsList = Arrays.asList(X);

// [....]

while((ListChecker.hasNext())) {   //continues as long as DNA Check has an index to go to
  if (xAsList.contains(ListChecker.next())) { //Checks A for X
    System.out.println("Good");       //Prints out good if the check is good
  } else {
    System.out.println("Bad");//Prints out bad if the check is bad
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RNA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String X [] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};  // Array to be checked against


        List<String>A = new ArrayList<String>();  // ArrayList to be imported

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How Many Sets of Strings do you want?");

        int T = scanner.nextInt(); // number of Strings to be imported

        scanner.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < T; i ++) {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            A.add(nextLine);  //imports stuff to add to array A
        }

        scanner.close();

        Iterator<String> ListChecker = A.iterator(); 
        while((ListChecker.hasNext())) {   //continues as long as DNA Check has an index to go to 

            if (A.contains(X)) {                  //Checks A for X
                System.out.println("Good");       //Prints out good if the check is good
            }
            else {

                System.out.println("Bad");        //Prints out bad if the check is bad
            }

            ListChecker.next();
        }

    }

}
```

Try this.

instead of `q.nextInt()` to use `q.nextLine()` to reset.

Answer (score 0):

Never use the same scanner for both nextInt() and nextLine(). They bug out. Use two scanners, one for ints, and one for strings. This will fix your program.